# How can one develop a rapid prototype for a web site while still using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms, rapid-prototyping

I am developing a website in which I want to use ASP.NET MVC 5 because the site has the potential to be quite large and require the separation of concerns that MVC provides. However, the client wants me to show him a "prototype" of the home page which is simplay a single page that shows an image, some text, and requires a user login (and he wants to see it ASAP). How can I reconcile the fact that developing a proper ASP.NET MVC site requries a large amount of initial time to set up with my requirement to quickly put together a page to show my client what he has in mind? Should Also, should I consider using Web Forms over Razor for this initial part of the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prototype it fast just by modifying default view, without creating models controllers etc.
Login functionallity exists out of the box in MVC.

Comment: So how would the login work? Should I just temporarilyy setup up authentication using the web.config file instead of using a SQL DB? What I want to show is a "floating" login box in front of the main page, with the main page content viewable around that box dimmed (need to find some JS for that I'm sure). Is the code that MVC generates automatially for authentication easily manipulated using CSS and JS so that the login box looks as i just described?

Comment: The question is, do you need wokring login funcntionallity or you just want to show a concept? In the first case you have to deal with ASP.NET MVC authorization system. Otherwise you can just use jquery to open/close login popup.

Comment: It needs to work, but just barely. For example, I simply need to show that if you enter an incorrect username/password, you can't view the rest of the site. Therefore, there is some HTTP redirection and validation involved.

Comment: Actually you can use the same AccountController from JS code. The answer is ASP.NET MVC does not slow down you prototyping unless you are familiar with the framework. If you aren't - just use a framework you are familiar with. But if you start with WebForms, apparently it will consume more time to go back to MVC. Knowing that MVC is the main framework nowdays in .NET word (asp.net vnext will contain only MVC, without webforms), I would consider using MVC.

Comment: I am petty new to MVC (I've read a lot but have no real dev experience), but I know that it is they way to go untimately. I thought about using WebForms as a solution briefly, but a quick google search showed exactly what you just stated - it's not worth it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can download one of MVC templates from Visual Studio.

Select `File > New Project > Online > Templates`.

You can find them also here (most of them are kept are up to date): https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=mvc&f[1].Value=mvc&f[1].Type=SearchText&f[0].Value=templates&f[0].Type=RootCategory&ac=4

Comment: Probably would save time, but I just personally dislike using someone else's code (unless it's part of a library or framework, of course).

Comment: Perhaps you should consider creating your own template?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of "rapid" prototyping, no?

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Single Page Application template is super quick to setup.  It'll run right out of the box.  Just add your image and text to the Home view.